# Django add foreign field to a query

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two tables: `menu` and `foodtype`

```
class Foodtype(models.Model):
    foodtype_en = models.TextField()
    active = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'foodtype'

class Menu(models.Model):
    title_en = models.TextField()
    description_en = models.TextField()
    active = models.BooleanField()
    id_foodtype = models.ForeignKey(Foodtype, models.DO_NOTHING, 
    id_home = models.ForeignKey('Home', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_home')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'menu'
```

Also, I generated a combined table:

```
class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foodtype_en = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ('id', 'title_en', 'active')
```

And I'm trying to get all the active `menu` records.

And I have:

```
menu = Menu.objects.filter(id_home=3,active=True).annotate(foodtype=foodtype)
```

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: The most important problem I see is that you're trying to get too close to the database. Let Django handle all that foreign key, table names and columns for you! You'll get much cleaner (thus easier to debug) code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like your need [source](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source):

```
foodtype_en = serializers.CharField(source='id_foodtype.foodtype_en')
```